# How to expand function with star using latex3?

Tags: expl3

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn { aaa, bbb, ccc }
  { \exp_args:Nco \DeclareMathOperator { #1 } { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\aaa$
$\bbb$
$\ccc$
\end{document}
```

I can expand the arguments of `\DeclareMathOperator` but not `\DeclareMathOperator*`. How to expand the arguments of `\DeclareMathOperator*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notwithstanding that it's common to say that `\DeclareMathOperator*` is a variant of `\DeclareMathOperator` (the same for all such commands), the command is just `\DeclareMathOperator`, which looks ahead to see whether `*` follows or not. Whether you write

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\aaa}{aaa}
```

or

```
\DeclareMathOperator *{\aaa}{aaa}
```

is completely immaterial: there are two tokens before the `{`.

So in your case you have to jump over two tokens, not just one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_map_inline:nn { aaa, bbb, ccc }
 {
  \exp_args:NNc \DeclareMathOperator * { #1 } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\aaa_{1\le i\le n} \bbb_{1\le j\le n} \ccc_{1\le k\le n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You just want `\exp_args:Nc` for the “no star” part. And `o` is useless, *unless* you want to use a macro expanding to a name, but that would be weird.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why are `\DeclareMathOperator` and `*` separate? Can you explain what `*` is? Or provide some links with existing answers. I tried searching but couldn't find any relevant explanation. I know that commands with and without `*` are logically separated internally. But I always thought there was a command for `*`, `*` was a part of the command, for example, `\DeclareMathOperator*` was a whole. But now it looks like a parameter of `\DeclareMathOperator`? It's just a relatively special parameter. Just like using `s` to mark in `xparse`.

Comment: @Clara I added some preliminaries

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand!